# VBA - how do I divide a range of cells by a fixed cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a column of values that I would like to divide by a fixed cell (say C3), and have the results in an adjacent column.

I would like this code to run to the last available row (with values) as well.

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: This is a job for a worksheet function. Why do you want to use VBA? If VBA it must be, I suggest you use a For ... Next loop. You can look up this term on the Internet and you will find plenty of code to construct your code. Then, if you still have a problem, show us your code and tell us the problem you have with it. We'll help you.

Comment: You've made many posts, and seem to have found the answer to them. Please mark the answers, when you get them, as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the posts, below the up/down arrow.  This helps us because it marks this question as solved, as well as giving credit to that user who helped your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source values were in, for instance, A1:A7 and you want to copy them to B1:B7 and divide by C3 at the same time, you could:

```
With ActiveSheet
    'Determine last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy the original values from column A to column B
    .Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

    'Copy / Pastespecial Divide using cell C3
    .Range("C3").Copy
    .Range("B1:B" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                          Operation:=xlDivide, _
                                          SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                          Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False                                              
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Do While

```
Do While Cells(iCol, 3).Value <> ""
    'Do some thing
    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop
```